# Google Apps Script function no longer working, debugger says local variables are undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

Let me preface my problem by mentioning that I don't have much experience with programming or Javascript, the code below I furnished from examples I found online.

The sendEmails function is meant to generate an email receipt on edit of the 7th column in the spreadsheet. The email should have the subject line "Returned Sample" and the message should contain information for which student the sample was taken from, the timestamp of when the sample was submitted, the text of the 7th column of the spreadsheet with notes about why the sample was rejected, and a list of the files contained in the submission. These emails should be sent to the sample submitter, whose email address is reported in the 2nd column of the spreadsheet.

```
function sendEmails(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 8 || e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 7).getValue() == "") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1,1,15).getValues();
  let studentName = rData[0][2];
  let timeStamp = rData[0][0];
  let email = rData[0][1];
  let notes = rData[0][7];
  let file1 = rData[0][8];
  let file2 = rData[0][9];
  let file3 = rData[0][10];
  let file4 = rData[0][11];
  let file5 = rData[0][12];
  let file6 = rData[0][13];


  let msg = `Your sample submission for ` + studentName + ` on ` + timeStamp + ` has been returned for the following reason: ` + `
 
  ` + notes + `
 
Please make the changes needed and resubmit. Thank you!


Files for this submission:
1: ` + file1 + `
2: ` + file2 + `
3: ` + file3 + `
4: ` + file4 + `
5: ` + file5 + `
6: ` + file6




  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Returned Sample", msg)
}
```

I ran the debugger and this is what it showed:

[Debugger results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaRxe.png)

Up until now this code was working fine, only recently it seems to have stopped working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Look into executions page

Answer (score 0):

**Sending emails with an installable onEdit trigger**

This is working for me:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Sheet0" || e.range.columnStart != 7 || !e.value) return;
  //e.source.toast("Gate1");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  const [ts,email,name,,,,,notes,file1,file2,file3,file4,file5,file6] = vs;
  let msg = `Your sample submission for ${name} on ${ts} has been returned for the following reason:\n ${notes}\nPlease make the changes needed and resubmit. Thank you!\n`;
  msg += `Files for this submission:\n`;
  msg += `1: ${file1}\n2: ${file2}\n3: ${file3}\n4: ${file4}\n5: ${file5}\n6: ${file6}`;
  MailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv, "Returned Sample", msg);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)